# AngularJs ng-submit cannot get the value of ng-model

Tags: angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel, ng-submit

I have this **HTML** :

```
<form ng-submit="addComment()">
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Shoutout</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="comment">
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

and in my **Controller** :

```
$scope.comment = "";

$scope.addComment = function(){
    console.log("Value from input", $scope.comment);
    $scope.comment = "test"
    console.log("New Value", $scope.comment);
}
```

It works fine when im typing on the `input` the model is updating and all. But when I press enter I expect the value from the input to be logged on the console. But it seems that it cannot get the updated value from the `ng-model`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing it as an argument:

```
<form ng-submit="addComment(comment)">
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Shoutout</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="comment">
  </md-input-container>
</form>

$scope.addComment = function(comment){
  console.log("Value from input", comment);
  $scope.comment = "test";
  console.log("New Value", comment);
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks. 1 question though. How do I make the `input` empty again?

Comment: @GreenFox Just do comment = "";

Comment: Im doing `$scope.comment = ""` inside the `addComment()` but it does not work. :(

Comment: What if you set it to null?

Comment: It seems that the problem is occuring due to the DOM is loaded before the Javascript because Im populating the views via ng-repeat based on the response from http. I solved it by putting a dynamic id on the input and used jquery to empty the input like `$('#comment_'+someid).val('');`

Answer (score 1):

It seems all correct have a look.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.comment = "";

    $scope.addComment = function() {
      console.log("Value from input", $scope.comment);
      $scope.comment = "test"
      console.log("New Value", $scope.comment);
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <form ng-submit="addComment()">
    <md-input-container flex>
      <label>Shoutout</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="comment">
    </md-input-container>
  </form>
  
  <p>{{"log-->> "+comment}}</p>
<div>
```